# multi-sort of associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Consider the following associative array

```
$arr = Array
(        
    [banana] => 2
    [cherry] => 1
    [orange] => 3
    [grapefruit] => 1
    [apple] => 1
)
```

I want to sort it in a way that would be similar to the PLSQL term: `A DESC, B ASC`
 (where A is the value and B is the key) meaning:

```
$arr = Array
(
    [orange] => 3
    [banana] => 2
    [apple] => 1
    [cherry] => 1
    [grapefruit] => 1        
)
```

so that orange and banana are first because of the VALUE, but then I have apple, cherry and grapefruit in alphabetical order because they have the same VALUE.

**What I tried:**

1. to run [ksort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) and then [asort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)/[rsort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) hoping that the second sort will bump up orange and banana to the beginning of the array without messing up the alphabetical  sort of the other 3 items. I was wrong. it does messes everything up. So I checked out:
2. [sort functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) and [array_multisort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php). But apparently it sorts  several arrays at once, or a multi-dimensional array. 

3. I also tried to define the following compare function:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    foreach ($a as $key1 => $val1) {
        foreach ($b as $key2 => $val2) {
            if($val1 == $val2){
                return strcmp($key1,$key2);
            }
            else if ($val1 > $val2){
                return 1;
            }
            else{ // $val1 < $val2
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

and call it with [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) but it also didn't work.

So my question is: is there a PHP method that implements the requested behavior?

**For Eugen:**
I tried it and it doesn't work
before sorting:

```
Array
(
    [lamb] => 3
    [rule] => 1
    [children] => 1
    [teacher] => 2
    [eager] => 1
)
```

and after sorting:

```
Array
(
    [children] => 1
    [eager] => 1
    [rule] => 1
    [teacher] => 2
    [lamb] => 3
)
```

Comment: How will you be using the resulting array?

Comment: @Galen in a very sophisticated and powerful way that was never seen on earth ;)

Comment: Regarding your first approach, it didn't work because PHP sorting is not stable (i.e. maintains order on equal values).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [array_multisort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

```
<?php
    $arr = Array
    (        
        'banana' => 2,
        'cherry' => 1,
        'orange' => 3,
        'grapefruit' => 1,
        'apple' => 1
    );

    $values = array_values($arr);
    $keys = array_keys($arr);

    //first sort by values desc, then sort by keys asc
    array_multisort($values, SORT_DESC, $keys, SORT_ASC, $arr);

    print_r($arr);
    // output:
    /*
    Array
    (
        [orange] => 3
        [banana] => 2
        [apple] => 1
        [cherry] => 1
        [grapefruit] => 1
    )
    */

?>
```

It works like this:

- for each column used to sort (values and keys for you), create new 1d array with its contents
- pass those 1d arrays to array_multisort function in your sorting order (so $values first, then $keys), add sort order for each array
- the last argument has to be the array which you want to sort

(Perhaps you will find [this explanation](http://isambard.com.au/blog/2009/07/03/sorting-a-php-multi-column-array/) easier to understand)

Comment: I don't know why you got -1, you got +1 from me as your solution indeed works, thanks!!!

Comment: @alfasin thanks :), people're so fast in downvoting and don't event explain why...

Comment: If we want to add multiple Sorting flags for each element we want to sort by, will it work?

Answer (score 3):

```
function polysortcmp($a, $b) {
  if ($a[1]<$b[1]) return 1;
  if ($a[1]>$b[1]) return -1;
  if ($a[0]<$b[0]) return -1;
  if ($a[0]>$b[0]) return 1;
  return 0;
}


function polysort(&$arr) {
  foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) $arr[$k]=array($k,$v);
  uasort($arr, "polysortcmp");
  foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) $arr[$k]=$v[1];
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I update the question to show you what is the result if I try it your way.

Comment: Sorry, misread you: I sorted by key first, then value - updated my answer.

Comment: Now it sorts alphabetically, but the VALUES are in ASC order instead of DESC. I updated my question to show you the current output of your code. You can take the example I gave and run it.

Comment: OK, third time is a charm, again updated my answer. For your information: the sort order is in `polysortcmp()` with `$a[1]` being the value and `$a[0]` being the key.

Answer (score 0):

array sorting function arsort used..

```
$arr = array(        
        'banana' => 2,
        'cherry' => 1,
        'orange' => 3,
        'grapefruit' => 1,
        'apple' => 1
    );

arsort($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Output

```
Array ( [orange] => 3 [banana] => 2 [apple] => 1 [grapefruit] => 1 [cherry] => 1 )
```

Comment: I tried arsort() and it doesn't work. it might work on that specific example I gave - but it will not work on general case.